# Trying to filter out a column in a dataframe by applying conditions on some other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 3 columns in a csv file : account_id , game_variant , no_of_games.... table looks something like this

```
account_id    game_variant   no_of_games
130               a             2
145               c             1
130               b             4
130               c             1
142               a             3
140               c             2
145               b             5
```

So, i want to extract no of games played in variant a,b,c,a∩b,b∩c,a∩c,a∩b∩c

I was able to extract games played in a,b,c individually by grouping with game_variant and doing sum over no_of_games but unable to logically put in the intersections part. Pls help me with that

```
data_agg = df.groupby(['game_variant']).agg({'no_of_games':[np.sum]})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution which will return the intersection based on a per-player level. This uses additionally the `defaultdict`, as this is very convenient for that case. I'll explain the code inline

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint  # only needed for pretty printing of dictionary

df = pandas.read_csv('df.csv', sep='\s+')  # assuming the data frame is in a file df.csv

# group by account_id to get subframes which only refer to one account.
data_agg2 = df.groupby(['account_id'])

# a defaultdict is a dictionary, where when no key is present, the function defined
# is used to create the element. This eliminates the check, if a key is
# already present or to set all combinations in advance.
games_played_2 = defaultdict(int)

# iterate over all accounts
for el in data_agg2.groups:
    # extract the sub-dataframe from the gouped function
    tmp = data_agg2.get_group(el)
    # print(tmp)  # you can uncomment this to see each account
    
    # This is in principle the same loop as suggested before. However, as not every
    # player has played all variants, one only has to create the number of combinations
    # necessary for that player
    for i in range(len(tmp.loc[:, 'no_of_games'])):
        # As now the game_variant is a column and not the index, the first part of zip
        # is slightly adapted. This loops over all combinations of variants for the
        # current account.
        for comb, combsum in zip(combinations(tmp.loc[:, 'game_variant'], i+1), combinations(tmp.loc[:, 'no_of_games'].values, i+1)):
            # Here, each variant combination gets a unique key. Comb is sorted, as the
            # variants might be not in alphabetic order. The number of games played for
            # each variant for that player are added to the value of all players before.
            games_played_2['_'.join(sorted(comb))] += sum(combsum)

pprint (games_played_2)

# returns
>> defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
            {'a': 5,
             'a_b': 6,
             'a_b_c': 7,
             'a_c': 3,
             'b': 9,
             'b_c': 11,
             'c': 4})
```

As you already extracted the number of games played by their variants, you could simply add them up. If you want to do that automatically, you could use `itertools.combinations` on that in a loop, which iterates over all possible combination lengths:

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint  # only needed for pretty printing of dictionary

df = pandas.read_csv('df.csv', sep='\s+')  # assuming the data frame is in a file df.csv

data_agg = df.groupby(['game_variant']).agg({'no_of_games':[np.sum]})

games_played = {}

for i in range(len(data_agg.loc[:, 'no_of_games'])):
    for comb, combsum in zip(combinations(data_agg.index, i+1), combinations(data_agg.loc[:, 'no_of_games'].values, i+1)):
        games_played['_'.join(comb)] = sum(combsum)

pprint(games_played)
```

returns:

```
>> {'a': array([5], dtype=int64),
>>  'a_b': array([14], dtype=int64),
>>  'a_b_c': array([18], dtype=int64),
>>  'a_c': array([9], dtype=int64),
>>  'b': array([9], dtype=int64),
>>  'b_c': array([13], dtype=int64),
>>  'c': array([4], dtype=int64)}
```

`'combinations(sequence, number)'` returns an iterator of all combinations of `number` elements in `sequence`. Therefore, to get all possible combinations, you have to iterate over all `numbers` from `1` to `len(sequence`. This is what the first for loop does.

The next `for` loop is composed of two iterators: One over the index of the aggregated data (`combinations(data_agg.index, i+1)`), one over the actual number of games played in each variant (`combinations(data_agg.loc[:, 'no_of_games'].values, i+1)`). So `comb` should always be a list of the variants, and combsum a list of the number of games played per variant. Note here, that to get all values you have to use `.loc[:, 'no_games']`, not `.loc['no_games']`, as the latter searches for an index named `'no_games'`, while it is a column name.

Then, I set the key of the dictionary to the combined string of the variant-list, and the value to the sum of the elements of the number of games played.

Comment: Hi @Jakob, I'm getting this eror(TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found) on the line games_played['_'.join(comb)] = sum(combsum). What should I do to resolve that and can you pls exlpain what you've coded, I didn't get it completely

Comment: and also why are you using aggregated data to get intersections, I mean how can you know who played both variants a and b or some other combinations without the account id ?

Comment: Ah, ok, you want to know the number of games played by one account in the variant combinations? This was not clear to me. Then you'd need indeed another approach. I'll add some explanation what I did in a sec. I am not sure why you get this error. If I read in the data frame you posted above (I copied and saved it in the file `df.csv`), This works for me. It might be that your index of `'data_agg'` is not the `'game_variants'`. Could you add the result from `print(data_agg.index)` to your post above?